# Clickhouse window aggregation of prices by bank

Tags: clickhouse

I have a test table in ClickHouse that I am prototyping of storage of FX price data.
The columns in this particular table are something like:

```
timestamp  DateTime64(6),
bank_name  String,
tob_bid    Float32,
tob_ask    Float32
```

What i'd like to achieve is a rolling array of the last quotes from each bank over time.

So e.g. if the table contained data like

```
2023-01-22 17:25:23.368889, 'LP1', 1.06782, 1.06784
2023-01-22 17:25:27.393059, 'LP1', 1.06781, 1.06784
2023-01-22 17:25:27.345757, 'LP2', 1.06780, 1.06787
2023-01-22 17:25:27.236824, 'LP3', 1.06781, 1.06785
2023-01-22 17:25:23.321132, 'LP2', 1.06779, 1.06785
2023-01-22 17:25:23.391159, 'LP1', 1.06780, 1.06782
2023-01-22 17:25:38.520492, 'LP3', 1.06779, 1.06783
```

I would like the results to be

```
2023-01-22 17:25:23.368889, [ 'LP1' ], [ 1.06782 ], [ 1.06784 ]
2023-01-22 17:25:27.393059, [ 'LP1' ], [ 1.06781 ], [ 1.06784 ]
2023-01-22 17:25:27.345757, [ 'LP1', 'LP2' ], [ 1.06781, 1.06780 ], [ 1.06784, 1.06787 ]
2023-01-22 17:25:27.236824, [ 'LP1', 'LP2', 'LP3' ], [ 1.06781, 1.06780, 1.06781 ], [ 1.06784, 1.06787, 1.06785 ]
2023-01-22 17:25:23.321132, [ 'LP1', 'LP2', 'LP3' ], [ 1.06781, 1.06779, 1.06781 ], [ 1.06784, 1.06785, 1.06785 ]
2023-01-22 17:25:23.391159, [ 'LP1', 'LP2', 'LP3' ], [ 1.06780, 1.06779, 1.06781 ], [ 1.06782, 1.06785, 1.06785 ]
2023-01-22 17:25:38.520492, [ 'LP1', 'LP2', 'LP3' ], [ 1.06780, 1.06779, 1.06779 ], [ 1.06782, 1.06785, 1.06783 ]
```

I.e. at every timestamp, the array is updating with the latest quote from each unique bank_name.

Is something like this possible in Clickhouse?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure can be simplified a lot but does the trick

```sql
WITH (
    arrayMap(i-> i = 1, arrayReverse(arrayEnumerateUniq(arrayReverse(
        groupArray(bank_name) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    ))))
) AS mask
SELECT
    timestamp,
    arrayFilter((x,y) -> y, groupArray(bank_name) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), mask) bank_names,
    arrayFilter((x,y) -> y, groupArray(tob_bid) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), mask) tob_bids,
    arrayFilter((x,y) -> y, groupArray(tob_ask) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), mask) tob_asks
FROM tt
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Comment: Amazing - that works brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
    timestamp,
    groupArray(bank_name) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS bank_names,
    groupArray(tob_bid) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS top_bids,
    groupArray(tob_ask) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS top_asks
FROM fx 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```